# How to disable pytest fixtures?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to run fixture tests separately from the classic unit tests.

For that end, I've marked all the fixtures with `@pytest.mark.fixtures` decorator, for example:

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def fs():
    pass
```

**test_something.py**

```
@pytest.mark.fixtures
def test_xxx(fs):
    pass

@pytest.mark.fixtures
def test_yyy():
    pass
```

and then ran two pytest commands (within tox):

```
pytest -v -m fixtures --junitxml={toxinidir}/tests/output/pytest-fixtures.xml
pytest -v -m "not fixtures" --junitxml={toxinidir}/tests/output/pytest.xml
```

The problem is that the second pytest run still creates my session fixture, although I will not use it because I'm skipping the tests marked with the above `fixtures` mark.

---

How can I disable the fixture on the second "not fixtures" run (or skip the session-scoped fixture)?

Comment: Actually I just tested this, and the fixture got _not_ loaded for me if I used the "not fixtures" filter. Are you sure you don't use it on any unmarked test? Or do you use an auto-used fixture?

Comment: MrBean Bremen you are absolutely correct! an auto-used fixture was accidentally included!